# Unity C# automatically scroll down to the selected item after choice

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollview, scrollbar

I've been looking for a specific way to code but didn't have any luck. Maybe I just couldn't find the right words to properly google this. I want to be able to do the following things with Dropdown:

1. The template should stay visible after I chose an item.
2. After closing the template, the scrollbar should automatically scroll down to the item (or skip to the item) I chose the next time I open the template.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766020/how-to-scroll-to-a-specific-element-in-scrollrect-with-unity-ui) page but I couldn't figure out how to use it since I'm not that bright on the coding side :(

Comment: You are better of implementing your own Dropdown then trying to fiddle this into the existing one :) 
You can still glance into the implementation and orient on it for the UI overlay etc

Comment: And then separate the issue .. e.g. look for [How to scroll to a specific element in ScrollRect with Unity UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766020/how-to-scroll-to-a-specific-element-in-scrollrect-with-unity-ui) as a separate issue ;)